# nested mysql queries into single query

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
$image=mysql_query("select * from carad order by carAdID DESC LIMIT 10");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($image))
    {
          $getimage=mysql_query("select * from carimage where carAdID='".$row["carAdID"]."' LIMIT 1");
          while($getimagerow=mysql_fetch_array($getimage))
          {
              echo(''); 
              echo('<a href="#" ><div class="simages"><img src="'.substr($getimagerow["carImageUrl"],1).'" width="600" height="400" /><div class="SliderContent">'.$row["catalogPrice"].'</div></div></a>');
          }
    }
```

I am using two queries one is before while loop and in while loop the id is comes from 1st query is there any best way to call these queries in a single query so it will optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ci.*
FROM carimage ci 
INNER JOIN 
(
    select * 
    from carad 
    order by carAdID DESC LIMIT 10
 ) c ON ci.carAdID = c.carAdID
 --May be you need to add LIMIT here as well
```